# Using a MS Access 2013 file in MS Access 2007

Tags: compatibility, microsoft-access

I've created a database in Access 2013. I thought this would work on Access 2007 which is on the computers out on site.

Unfortunately since I added in things like queries to generate reports for extracting certain data this is no longer the case.

The file opens however when tyring to open the form an error message comes up saying some features are not supported.

Anyone know of a way round this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Although MS Access 2013 can save database files in the older .mdb format (as opposed to the newer .mdbx), not all features are compatible or can be saved in the older format.

Access 2013 *should* give you a warning when saving to the older format with unsupported features.  I have personally seen it do so, but maybe it doesnt in all cases.

Regardless, the only way to get around this is to not use the newer features in your database, or to upgrade the other version of Access.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *are* using save as and selecting the .mdb 2007 format?

Comment: Thanks for trying guys.In 2013 the only options under Save As are Access Database, Access 2002-3 Database, Access 2000 Database and Template (ACCDT) which is the one it was saved in originally when emailed to me. However when opened on Access 2007 the only option under Save As after Downloading is Access 2007.

Apologies if I'm missing something here, don't have much experience of Access at all.